# Cancel countdowntimer if user navigates away from activity (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an activity that counts down 60 seconds, however, if the user navigates away from the activity, either using a back button on screen or if the press the Android back button, I need the countdown timer to cancel or it just carries on in the background. This is the code I have to start the timer:

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer

class GamePlay : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
// play music, though it's cutting out after 15 seconds for some reason
        var musicPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backgroundmusic)
        musicPlayer?.start()
// start the timer
        object : CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
            override fun onFinish() {
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext,Results::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
                time.text = ""+p0/1000
            }
        }.start()
    }
}
// function for clicking the back button on screen
fun goToMainMenu(view:View){
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext,MainMenu::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

I'd have thought it would be along the lines of `CountDownTime.cancel()` but I cannot figure out how to do it, and I don't know how I could get it to do it if the user uses the system back button either.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just set the CountDownTimer as val and the call the val.cancel()

create property

```
private lateinit var timer: CountDownTimer
```

set the val as CountDownTimer

```
timer = object : CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
            override fun onFinish() {
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext,Results::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
                time.text = ""+p0/1000
            }
        }.start()
```

set the timer.cancel() on backpress function

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    timer.cancel()
}
```

Comment: ah! thank you
how do I call the cancel if they use the system back button to go back to the previous activity?

Comment: @Maff do it in onDestroy callback which is called whenever your activity is closed

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

First of all save your timer to field:

```
class GamePlay : AppCompatActivity() {

    val timer = CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
        override fun onFinish() {
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext,Results::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
            time.text = ""+p0/1000
        }
    }

   ....
}
```

Then in in onCreate() start it and in onDestroy() stop

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   ... 
   // A bunch of other stuff

   timer.start()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy()
   timer.cancel()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep a reference to your timer, and then call `cancel()` in your activity's onDestroy.

```
class GamePlay : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var timer: CountDownTimer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // play music, though it's cutting out after 15 seconds for some reason
        var musicPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backgroundmusic)
        musicPlayer?.start()          

        timer = CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
            override fun onFinish() {
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext,Results::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
                time.text = ""+p0/1000
            }
        }.start()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        timer.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: If user will hide the app (without closing it) by pressing home button and the returns to it the timer will be canceled and won't start again

Comment: That's actually not true, because onPause is called. But you have a point that there is a lack of symmetry in my solution. I'll update it.

Comment: You mentioned the home button, which will go to onPause. If the activity is cleaned up it will go through onStop and _maybe_ onDestroy. onDestroy is not guaranteed and should not be used in most circumstances. Either way, my edit has cleaned it up so it will always be started and stopped appropriately.

Comment: When you press home button then `onPause()` and `onStop()` are called. When you return to the activity `onRestart()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` are called. Try it yourself :)

Comment: It appears I was mistaken. Bringing another activity to the forefront will pause, home will stop. Thanks.